# Primefaces style is applied on <span> instead of <input>

Tags: css, input, primefaces, styles, html

I'm working with primefaces on a screen where I used calendar and autocomplete

I got the UI from the designer and started integration, I assigned styles like this

```
<p:calendar styleClass="xyz" />
```

the output is

```
<span id="bla" class="xyz" >
    <input type="text" class="some other classes here" />
</span>
```

so my styles all fail

Now I need to apply styles on input directly instead of the spans

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you solve it by rearranging your CSS?:

```
.xyz input {
/* some weird styling here */
}
```

Comment: it's not a solution ... simply the designer will update his prototype and I will need to copy and paste every single change into my css .. it is the solution proposed on their issue tracker and the issue was closed as "not to be fixed"

Comment: Mark's answer is correct and it is actually the solution. Alternative is overriding .ui-inputfield.hasDatepicker css selector.

Comment: okay that's fine .. all workarounds in my mind now thank you all

Answer (score 1):

This is problematic if you rely on Bootstrap CSS for example. Form controls needs the class `form-control`, but when you add `styleClass="form-control"` for `p:calendar`, the surrounding span gets the class instead of the input, which totally messes with the design. I think there should be a `inputStyleClass` attribute for the `p:calendar` tag, the same way there is a `tableStyleClass` tag for `p:dataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using jQuery to add the form-control class to the input field:

```
$(".mycalendar input:first-child").addClass("form-control");

p:calendar id="date1" value="#{bean.date1}" styleClass="mycalendar" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this trick if you are using material design:

```
:host /deep/ .ui-inputtext{
   /* Your Crazy Custom Style*/
}
```